# Password Protect My Website

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, webserver

I have recently created a new Amazon EC2 instance using Amazon Linux AMI. What is the best way to force a user accessing the domain to enter a username/password before allowing access to the site?

I am currently using apache http server, and saw some resources indicating I need to use a .htaccess file, but was looking for a more concise explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you are looking for is server-level access control (i.e. no modifications to your application), you can utilize basic authentication.  This is implemented at the Apache web-server level and can be controlled on a directory-by-directory basis if desired using .htaccess files.

Here is a link to the Apache documentation

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html

Here is a simple example of how to implement

http://doc.norang.ca/apache-basic-auth.html

Comment: This helped but I am now having an authentication issue, I will most likely open up a new question with the details.

Answer (score 29):

### Password Protecting Site via Htaccess

1. Create a .htaccess file with the following in the to-be-protected folder:

   ```
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Password Protected Area"
   AuthUserFile /var/www/admin/.htpasswd
   Require valid-user
   ```
2. Create a `.htpasswd` file in the same or preferably a folder that is outside `/var/www`.

   For demonstration, I used a dummy path above. The .htpasswd file should contain your password salt 
   use [this generator](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/) to create your `.htpasswd` file.
3. Assuming you are using ubuntu, you have to enable htaccess override via this file: `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`

   Change the "AllowOverride None" to "AllowOverride All" in:

   ```
   <Directory /var/www/>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride None
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
   </Directory>
   ```

note: you may need to edit in ssh via command line: `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default`

4. `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload`

Comment: In general, you should only use .htaccess files when you don't have access to the main server configuration file. There is, for example, a common misconception that user authentication should always be done in .htaccess files, and, in more recent years, another misconception that mod_rewrite directives must go in .htaccess files. This is simply not the case. You can put user authentication configurations in the main server configuration, and this is, in fact, the preferred way to do things. Likewise, mod_rewrite directives work better, in many respects, in the main server configuration.

Comment: please give credit to 'Apache.org's Apache Tutorial' when you copy and paste the whole chunk of text.

Comment: Would have done it,  but I had only 7 chars left. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html paragraph "When (not) to use .htaccess files"

Comment: great answer. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate a password username+password string for authentication and write it to a file.

- You can use [HTTP password generator tool](http://www.asempt.com/tool/http-password-generator) to do this.
- Copy paste the string you obtained to a new file (.htpasswd) anywhere outside your Webroot (better to keep anywhere inside home directory of the user).
- Add following lines in your .htaccess file.

> ```
> AuthType Basic
> AuthName "Require Authentication"
> AuthUserFile [PATH_TO_FILE]/.htpasswd
> Require valid-user
> ```

- If the password is not triggering, check the permission of .htaccess file.
- If authetication fails, check the existance of .htpasswd file in the specified location. (Make sure your user account has enough privileges on .htpasswd file to read)
- You do not need to restart server to achieve this.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

gnerate encrypted password and add to .htpasswd file

```
$ htpasswd -nbm username Password
```

*.htaccess file entry*

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /absolute/path/to/password/file
Require valid-user
```

[For more details go through this blog post - iCodefy](http://icodefy.com/password-protection-to-website-using-htaccess/)