# Password protect directory in AWS EC2 running Apache/Linux

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

As the title says, I have an AWS EC2 instance with Apache. It's a Linux server. I want to password protect one directory. I was following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18178857/989722

htaccess:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /var/www/admin/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Created a proper .htpasswd file, but wondering if there's another step.

However, it's not working (i.e., directory isn't protected).  I restarted my server and that didn't help. Wondering if I need to change something in my config file.

If I look at the contents of the directory where I placed my .htaccess file, using terminal `ls`, the .htaccess file isn't visible. I uploaded it using SFTP and see it using my FTP application, but maybe it's not actually there. Same thing for my .htpasswd file.

Comment: I would strongly advise against storing your `.htpasswd` file under your webroot (`www`). Anyone with a login can access the entire file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dumb mistake.

Needed to add this to my server config file:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/MYPROTECTEDDIRECTORY>
AllowOverride All     
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of addition to above step.

1. config file to update directory for AllowOverride is available via vi editor
   `sudo vi /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`
2. After saving restart the apache server
   `sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart`